# Spring Boot Get Key from Value in property file

Tags: spring-boot, properties-file

In Spring Boot is there any way to get the key from value , i have the properties file which has the below key value map

```
index.properties
employee_index=id,emaployeename,department,address,companyname,salary
```

from above prop file, i will pass the department then i need to get the employee_index.